# Finding Fourier coefficients?

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

The question is as follows:

$f(x) = \cos(\pi x)$, $g(x) = f(x+2010)$. I need to find the sum of all of $g$'s Fourier coefficients from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I know that $f=g$.

Therefore $g$'s $n$th Fourier coefficient is: $\frac {1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\pi x)e^{-inx} dx$, which comes down to  $\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^\pi \cos(\pi x)\cos(nx) dx$.

This is where I'm stuck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $cos(x) = Re(e^{ix})$ or integrating by parts twice the first integral form

Comment: If $f(x)=\cos\pi x$ and $g(x)=f(x+2010)$, then $f\ne g$. Please check the formulation of your problem.

Comment: @Yiorgos But $g(x)=f(x+2010)=\cos(\pi x+1005\cdot(2\pi))=\cos(\pi x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @TooOldForMath: Sorry - Correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration by parts gives

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\pi x)\cos(nx)dx &= \int_{-\pi}^\pi (\frac{1}{\pi} \sin(\pi x))^\prime \cos(nx) dx\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\pi^2)(-1)^n + \frac{n}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin~(\pi x)\sin(nx)dx
\end{align}
$$

Integrating by parts again gives

$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(\pi x)\sin(nx) dx = \frac{n}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\pi x)\cos(nx) dx$$

Setting $A=\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\pi x)\cos(nx) dx$ we see

$$A=\frac{2}{\pi}\sin(\pi^2)(-1)^n+\frac{n^2}{\pi^2} A$$

Simplifying gives

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(\pi x)\cos(nx)dx=\frac{A}{\pi}=\frac{2\sin(\pi^2)(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-\pi^2}$$

The Fourier series of $f=g$ is therefore

$$\frac{\sin(\pi^2)}{\pi^2}+2\sin(\pi^2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2-\pi^2}\cos(nx)$$

It is convergent and equal to $f$ for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.